# envMap and MeshPhong Material in three.js

Tags: reflection, three.js

I tried to add an environmental map to my PhongMaterial, but when I do so my geometry disappears. Here goes my code:

```
var reflection = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( [ 'textures/hdr/pos-x.png', 'textures/hdr/neg-x.png', 'textures/hdr/pos-y.png', 'textures/hdr/neg-y.png', 'textures/hdr/pos-z.png', 'textures/hdr/neg-z.png' ] );
    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( 
    {   
        map: textures.color,
        normalMap: textures.normal,
        specularMap: textures.specular,
        envMap: reflection,
        combine: THREE.MixOperation, 
        reflectivity: 0.25,
        specular: 0xffffff,

    } 
    );
```

If I change the Phong to a Lambert material, I can see thee geometry and the reflection. Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

Update: I have found out that the normal and the envMap don't work together. So the envMap works if I don't you use a normal Map and the normalMap only works without the envMap. Is this a known issue and is there any way I can add both maps to my mehsphong material?

Answer (score 2):

EnvMap and normalMap can work together - [example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_normalmap). You must have spotlight on the scene . Otherwise you will get "'vWorldPosition' : undeclared identifier" error.

Seems to be the reason is in phong shader:

```
"#if MAX_SPOT_LIGHTS > 0 || defined( USE_BUMPMAP )",
    "varying vec3 vWorldPosition;",
"#endif"
```